# Trouble with finding floor(log2(int)) using binary search in O(log2(amount_bits))

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary

In our algorithms class, we've got an extra question in the lab session by the professor. Find the floor(log2(x)) for an int of n bits in log2(n) steps (e.g. when T = uint64_t, then n = 64).

We've found that we should be able to solve this with binary search, but we get an off by 1 result or an endless loop in certain edge cases. We're scratching our heads for some time, but cannot seem to get this right. How do we best deal with this? We've tried to reason with the invariant trick as discussed [here](https://zhu45.org/posts/2018/Jan/12/how-to-write-binary-search-correctly/), but it seems to be a little more complex than. E.g. for a decimal number, when choosing between bit 7 or 6 is difficult as 128 is larger than 100, but 64 is smaller. Unfortunately, when mitigating this, we break some edge cases.

EDIT: As noted below, this is purely an academic question with low to none usability in real-life scenario's.

Here is our code so far:

```
//
//   h      l
//   76543210
// 0b01000001 = 65
//

using T = unsigned char;

int lgfloor(T value)
{
    assert(value > 0);

    int high = ((sizeof(value) * 8) - 1);
    int low = 0;
    int mid = 0;
    T guess = 0;

    while (high > low)
    {
        mid = (low + ((high - low) / 2));
        guess = static_cast<T>(1) << mid;

        printf("high: %d, mid: %d, low: %d\n", high, mid, low);

        if (value < guess)
        {
            high = mid - 1;
        }
        else
        {
            low = mid;
        }
    }

    return low;
}
```

We have created the following unit tests (using GoogleTest):

```
TEST(LgFloor, lgfloor)
{
    ASSERT_DEATH(lgfloor(-1), "Assertion `value > 0' failed.");
    ASSERT_DEATH(lgfloor(0), "Assertion `value > 0' failed.");

    ASSERT_EQ(lgfloor(1), 0);
    ASSERT_EQ(lgfloor(2), 1);
    ASSERT_EQ(lgfloor(64), 6);
    ASSERT_EQ(lgfloor(100), 6);
}
```

Thanks in advance,
with kind regards,

Marten

Comment: Is `char` signed or unsigned on your platform? If it's unsigned you're in for some fun with your assertions. Since it's recommended to only perform shifts on unsigned quantities but you want tests with signed inputs, you kind of need to figure out which one you want to use.

Comment: @Max Langhof The algorithm also fails equivalently for `using T = unsigned long long int`, which was the type used when we originally developed this method.

Comment: I'm just trying to help you improve the question. I understand that these nitpicks are not _your_ main concern, but it's irritating for others to get stuck on these problems when they aren't what you care about.

Comment: In any case, what did you find when debugging this? _Which_ test case fails, and what are the steps your search is taking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a proper exit condition. Let's say `y = floor(lg2(x))`. You should exit the loop when `2^low <= x` and `x < 2^(low+1)`. But if `high == low+1` then this is fulfilled, yet you do not currently exit. Just do:

```
while (high > low+1)
{
```

It is good to look at invariants in your loop. For example, we could try to maintain `x < 2^high` (that would require starting at `sizeof(T)*8`, not `sizeof(T)*8 - 1`). Then all you need to do is bisecting until `low == high-1` and you are done.

We can maintain this invariant by only changing `high` to `mid` if `x < 2^mid`, i.e. if `value < guess`. That's the first case:

```
if (value < guess)
  high = mid;
```

We further must maintain `2^low <= x = value`. So, in the else branch (which requires `2^mid == guess < value`, we can safely set `low = mid`.

```
else
  low = mid;
```

All that is left is to prove that the loop always progresses. Since `high > low+1`, we have `high - low >= 2` and thus `mid != low` and `mid != high`. Clearly, we are reducing the interval (by half) each iteration.

So there you go:

```
int lgfloor(T value)
{
    assert(value > 0);

    int high = (sizeof(value) * 8);
    int low = 0;

    while (high > low+1)
    {
        int mid = (low + ((high - low) / 2));
        T guess = static_cast<T>(1) << mid;

        printf("high: %d, mid: %d, low: %d\n", high, mid, low);

        if (value < guess)
            high = mid;
        else
            low = mid;
    }

    return low;
}
```

---

I should of course note that there are dedicated intrinsics for this exact purpose in modern hardware. For example, search [Intel's intrinsics guide](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#cats=Bit%2525252520Manipulation) for `_BitScanReverse` which will complete in a fraction of the cycles the above code would take.

One way or another, asymptotic runtimes that depend on bit-width are pretty meaningless when dealing with fixed-width types such as C++' integral ones (although the question has educational value still).

Comment: `if (value < guess) { high = mid; } else { low = mid + 1; }` causes lgfloor(1) to fail. `if (value < guess) { high = mid - 1; } else { low = mid; }` causes an endless loop in lgfloor(2): `high: 2, mid: 1, low: 1`. Fixing one case causes others to fail. We suspect that this is not the average binary search application, but has an additional difficulty which we constantly seem to miss. We debugged various variations of this method, but seem to constantly fail one test or another.

Comment: @MartenBE In that case just add a check for `guess == value` and return `mid`. Note that `low` can never reach `high` in your implementation, so if at any point `high` is the correct guess then you currently have no way of returning `high` (you only ever return `low`). Alternatively, did you try `high = mid` and `low = mid` yet? Again, the correct solution should be really obvious if you sit down with a piece of paper and do it by hand once (which I admit to not having done myself).

Comment: We've tried that, but such a solution fails lgfloor(100): `if (value == guess) { return mid; } else if (value < guess) { high = mid - 1; } else { low = mid + 1; }`. Additionally: `if (value < guess) { high = mid; } else { low = mid; }` also gives an endless loop: `high: 7, mid: 6, low: 6`. It's really tricky :p

Comment: Ok `value == guess` is of course wrong. What you'd need to check is if you are at the leftmost bit. That is, `if ((guess ^ value) < guess) return mid;`.

Comment: Also note that there is an intrinsic that does this whole job instruction for you (in essentially O(1)): [`_BitScanReverse`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#cats=Bit%2525252520Manipulation). Doesn't qualify for the assignment (I mean, you could argue that the inbuilt operations for addition, division shifts and comparisons are all O(numBits) just the same), but just in case you ever have to do this in practice, you know.

Comment: @MartenBE I wrote it down on paper now and what do you know, the answer became clear.

Comment: `if ((guess ^ value) < guess) { return mid; } else if (value < guess) { high = mid - 1; } else { low = mid + 1; }` did the trick for the 3-way branch solution! It was indeed a problem with the comparison. I see you added a 2-way branch solution also: I've marked it as the right answer, thank you for your help! I'm also interested on what you wrote on that paper :)

Comment: This solution doesn't satisfy the `O(log(n))` constraint.

Comment: @YvesDaoust The question does not unambiguously specify, but I recall (from an earlier, now deleted version of the question) that the author asked for `O(log(representationBits))`, not `O(log(log(x)))`. Or in other words, please source your claim that `n = lg2(x)` and not `n = sizeof(x)` (if it was the former, why would the question go out of its way to say "`O(log(n))` where n is the number of bits"?)

Comment: @MaxLanghof: the question is indeed quite ambiguous. The title says `log(amount_bits)`, while the body says `log(n)` for an int of `n` bits. None of these expressions is explained. If the "simple" interpretation is taken, it would make sense to pass `n` as a parameter.

Comment: amount_bits is the amount of bits used for the datatype of T (which is why sizeof is used in the code). E.g. T = uint64_t, means that n = 64.

Answer (score 0):

Endless loop is due to this line:

```
 mid = (low + ((high - low) / 2));
```

if `high` and `low` is differ by 1, the result could be `mid == low` and then at the condition that cause `low = mid` inside the while loop, you resulted in checking the same condition forever. My suggestion would be, if you have `low = mid` in the loop, you have to make sure your `mid != low` in that case. So just check this before the assignment and do `low = mid+1` instead if that happens.

Answer (score 0):

The solution must be found in `lg(n)` steps, which means that an initialisation such as `low= 0`, `high= 32` won't work, because it would take `5` steps in every case and wouldn't work for `x` larger than `2^32`. A correct solution must combine a first *geometric* search where you double the exponent, then a standard dichotomic search.

```
# Geometric search
low= 0
high= 1
while (1 << high) <= x:
    low= high
    high+= high

# Dichotomic search
while high - low > 1:
    mid= (high + low) >> 1
    if x < mid:
        high= mid
    else:
        low= mid
```

Answer (score -1):

Seems like you just have to shift if to the right 'log' times, until you have a '1'.

```
using T = unsigned char;

int lgfloor(T value)
{
  assert(value > 0);

  int log = 0;
  while(value != 1) {
    value >> 1;
    log++;
  }
  return log;
}
```

Comment: This solution is O(amount_bits) instead of O(log2(amount_bits)).